# Dynamic Struct Array allocation within a function

Tags: c, multithreading, dynamic

I am trying to allocate an array of structs within a function.

My struct is as follows:

```
 typedef struct{
      uint16_t  taskNumber;
      uint16_t  taskType;          
      double    lat;               
      double    lon;               
      double    speed;             
      uint8_t   successCriteria;   
      uint16_t  successValue;      
      uint8_t   nextPoint;      
 }missionPoint;
```

In my code I declare a missionPoint-pointer which I then pass into the function that will dynamically allocate it after parsing a file and figuring out how big it needs to be.
Currently this is how my code looks:

```
 missionPoint* mission;    //declaring the pointer
 parseMission(mission);
```

The parseMission function will then parse a specific file and find out how many missionPoints I need and will then allocate it in the following manner:

```
 mission = (missionPoint*) malloc(n * sizeof(missionPoint));
```

where n is the parsed number of missionPoints I need.

The problem is that within the function I can see the proper values but not outside of it; once the function returns it's like nothing happened.

I would appreciate your help in making it so that the function modifies the original pointer and I can see the data from outside the function.

Comment: You should reorder your structure so it's properly aligned. One easy way to do this is to order members in order of decreasing size. Or you could just move the third `uint16_t` to right after the first two, and the two `uint8_t`'s to right after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the pointer, i.e. a double pointer, because the address itself is going to be modified:

```
missionPoint *mission;
parseMission(&mission);
```

The argument of `parseMission` should now be of type `missionPoint **` instead of `missionPoint *`:

```
*mission = (missionPoint*) malloc(n * sizeof(missionPoint));
```

This wouldn't be necessary if you only wanted to modify the memory `mission` is pointing to, but it cannot be avoided since you are assigning a new value to the pointer itself.

Also note that casting the return value of `malloc` is not necessary in C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is being modified outside the function; now if within the function I wanted to modify part of the array, I would think `(*mission[count]).taskNumber=20` would modify it, but it only modifies it within the function, how would I attain this?

Comment: Try putting parentheses like this: `(*mission)[count].taskNumber=20`

Comment: One last question, to get the size of this struct array (how many structs), how cna I accomplish this? I tried the approach of `sizeof(mission)/sizeof(mission[0])` but this did not work; `sizeof(mission[0]` returns `32` and `sizeof(mission)` returns `4` so the call returns as `0`.

Comment: `sizeof` is a static operator, evaluated at compile-time, for data whose size is known at compile-time. You can't use `sizeof` to measure the size of a dynamically allocated block of memory. Rather, you need to keep the `n` variable after the allocation and use it as the size.

Comment: Great, I thought I would have to save the n variable, but it makes sense now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference (i.e. pointer) to the `mission` pointer rather than the value of the `mission` pointer itself.  So the declaration of your function would look like:

```
void parseMission(missionPoint** pointer_ref);
```

rather than:

```
void parseMission(missionPoint* pointer_val);
```

then pass the address of `mission` (i.e., `&mission`) as the argument value for `parseMission`.

Answer (score 1):

Think that a pointer in C is just a integer, storing some memory address.
Think that `malloc` allocates some memory and returns you the address of this memory (a new pointer).
Understand that this snippet will print "2", regadless of what the called function does with the passed value.

```
int a = 2;
doSomething(a);
printf("%d\n",a);
```

Once you understand all this, you can predict what this code will produce, and why you need to pass the "reference to the pointer" (pointer to the pointer) instead of of the pointer itself (value of the pointer) to your allocator function.

```
void remalloc(char * p1) {
     printf("pointer before remalloc (inside function): %X\n",(unsigned int)(p1));
     free(p1);
     p1 = (char*)malloc(200000);
     printf("pointer after remalloc (inside function): %X\n",(unsigned int)(p1));
}

int main(){
   char * p;
   printf("pointer before malloc: %X\n",(unsigned int)(p)); 
   p = (char*)malloc(10);
   printf("pointer after malloc: %X\n",(unsigned int)(p));
   remalloc(p);
   printf("pointer after remalloc: %X\n",(unsigned int)(p));
}
```